Как отобразить гиф файл с анимацией в Tkinter?
Помогите указать на ошибку в коде. Я хотел сделать так, чтобы файл.gif с анимацией передвигался в зад-перёд. 
Подзабыл с модулем tkinter.
Код:
import turtle
from turtle import *
import tkinter

register_shape("images/tenor.gif")

man = Turtle()
man.shape("images/tenor.gif")

man.forward(50)                   # не уверен.

Хотелось бы узнать, как можно с помощью модуля tkinter использовать для выведения анимированных GIF-файлов.

Как вариант:
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

frameCnt = 8                # количество кадров изображений в данных GIF.
frames = [PhotoImage(file='loading.gif',format = f'gif -index {i}') for i in range(frameCnt)]

def update(ind):
    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    if ind == frameCnt:
        ind = 0
    label.configure(image=frame)
    root.after(100, update, ind)
    
label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.after(0, update, 0)
root.mainloop()


